# How don't allow duplicates in the items array when condition and field name are the same?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have this piece of HTML code:

```
<select id="table" name="table">
  <option></option>
  <option value="asset_locations">Asset Locations</option>
  <option value="companies">Company</option>
</select>
<select id="fields" name="fields">
  <option></option>
  <option value="asset_locations_id">asset_locations_id</option>
  <option value="companies_id">companies_id</option>
  <option value="region_id">region_id</option>
  <option value="asset_locations_name">asset_locations_name</option>
  ...
</select>
<select id="conditions">
  <option></option>
  <option value="=">Equal to</option>
  <option value="<>">Not Equal to</option>
  <option value=">">Greater Than (Strictly)</option>
  ...
</select>
<select id="condition_value_1" multiple="multiple" style="display: none">
  <option></option>
</select>
<button id="add" style="display: none">Add</button>
```

And I am building an object as follow:

```
$(function() {
  ...
  var list = {}; 
  var items = [];
  ...

  $('#add').click(function() {
    var data_field = $('#fields :selected').val();
    var data_condition = $('#conditions :selected').val();
    var data_values = $('#condition_value_1').val();

    var item = [
      data_field,
      data_condition,
      data_values
    ];

    var key = JSON.stringify(item);
    if (list[key] === 1) return; // skip

    list[key] = 1;
    items.push(item);

    console.log(list);
    console.log(items);
  });
});
```

It works but it allow duplicates for `data_field` and `data_condition` meaning they should be unique and update it's `data_values` only. For example, if you execute the code above and add some values for a given condition you should end with the following at the console:

```
Object {["asset_locations_name","=",["1212341047","1212341048","1212369641"]]: 1}
```

Now if you run it for a second time and change the `data_values` you will end with the following at the console:

```
Object {["asset_locations_name","=",["1212341047","1212341048","1212369641"]]: 1, ["asset_locations_name","=",["1212341047","1212341048","1212369653"]]: 1}
```

As you notice both `data_field` and `data_condition` are the same an even they share idem values only one is different. A correct output should be:

```
Object {["asset_locations_name","=",["1212341047","1212341048","1212369641", "1212369653"]]: 1}
```

Where the `data_values` gets updated with new values and the `data_field` and `data_condition` keeps unique.

The conditions on second+ execution in this cases would be:

- if `data_field` and `data_condition` remain the same then look for it's values and update them properly without allow duplicates.
- other than  that will be a valid option to add a new entry.

Here is another example from the above:

```
1st exec:
input: asset_locations_name, in, ["1212341047","1212341048","1212369641"]
output: Object {["asset_locations_name","=",["1212341047","1212341048","1212369641"]]: 1}

2nd exec:
input: asset_locations_name, in, ["1212341047","1212341048","1212369653"]
output: Object {["asset_locations_name","=",["1212341047","1212341048","1212369641", "1212369653"]]: 1}

3rd exec:
input: asset_locations_name, not in, ["1212341047","1212341048","1212369653"]
output: Object {["asset_locations_name","=",["1212341047","1212341048","1212369641"]]: 1, ["asset_locations_name","<>",["1212341047","1212341048","1212369653"]]: 1}
```

Notice how in the `2nd` exec I keep the same entry but updating it's `data_values` which is the right and wanted behavior.

Notice how in the `3rd` exec we are changing the value of the `data_condition` making it to be a new entry no matter if the `data_values` are the same. If there is any typo and I am not aware or you didn't understand anything let me know and I try to do my best to get this clear.

> Note: the solution should be compatible with older browser. (We're updating but until then I need to use old browser compatibility)

I leave a working Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/reynierpm/tw4pgr66/).

How can I achieve this? Any help?

**Update: Values doesn't get accumulate if keys are keep**

Currently the solution has an issue where values doesn't get accumulate when keys are keep and the should.

There is an update version of the Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/reynierpm/tw4pgr66/4/) showing up the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an ideal situation to use an ES6 [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). But as you are asking for backwards compatibility, I will suggest this:

```
var items = {};


//...
var key = JSON.stringify([data_field, data_condition]); // only these two!

items[key] = item; // will overwrite if same key

// if you need to have it as an array:
for (key in items) {
    console.log(items[key]);
}
// ...
```

Your updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tw4pgr66/1/). I also included a function if you ever need to convert this `items` object to a plain array.

#### Accumulating selected values

For accumulating the values that are selected for the same key, you could use this code for updating `items[key]`:

```
if (typeof data_values === 'string') {
    items[key] = data_values; // no accumulation for simple values
} else {
    items[key] = items[key] || [];
    // make values cumulative, while avoiding duplicates:
    for (var i = 0; i < data_values.length; i++) {
      if (items[key].indexOf(data_values[i]) == -1)
        items[key].push(data_values[i]);
    }
}
```

This changes a bit the structure, as now only the `data_values` are stored as value, so the `toArray` function needs to take the rest from the key:

```
function toArray(items) {
  result = [];
  for (key in items) {
    // decode key, and concatenate the values array to it
    result.push(JSON.parse(key).concat([items[key]]));
  }
  return result;
}
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tw4pgr66/9/)

Comment: same problem from my side as days ago :-( this should be compatible for now with older browsers, my apologies

Comment: Please specify this requirement in your question. I will update my answer.

Comment: already did, see the note at the bottom and would be great if you update the fiddle example so I can see it working on live, thx

Comment: if I am following you then I can get rid of this check `if (list[key] === 1) return;` right?

Comment: Indeed, because I understand you want to update the previous value in case of a duplicate submission. NB: I added an updated fiddle.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for and your solution works like a charm, many thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128094/discussion-between-trincot-and-reynierpm).